# getting date numbers from string

Tags: javascript

lets say I have two string that looks like this:

1. Monday, November 13, 2008 - 3:12pm
2. Friday, November 1, 2008 - 6:53pm

Is there a Regex pattern I can use to extract the day number?

I am currently using Javascript, and would like to make a function to do the heavy lifting.. I have started on one below, but cant seem to get it working.

```js
function extractDate(str) {
  
  return str;
}
```

Please share with me a way to make it work

Comment: What format do you want the date in? Because that's already a date format...

Comment: what should be your expected result?

Comment: DD so for example 13 or 1 @decpk

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a Regex function that will get rid of the day of the week and time in the elements:

```regex
/(january|february|march|april|june|july|august|september|october|november|december) \d{1,2}, \d{4}/gi
```

Here's a working example of that regex, then logging it.

```js
const x = document.getElementById("target").children;
const dateRegex = (/(january|february|march|april|june|july|august|september|october|november|december) \d{1,2}, \d{4}/gi);

function extractDate(str) {
  const parsedDate = str.match(dateRegex);
  return parsedDate;
}

for (let i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
  // Return as string
  var strDate = extractDate(x[i].innerText).toString();
  // Return as array
  var arrDate = extractDate(x[i].innerText);
  
  console.log(strDate);
}
```

```html
<ul id="target">
  <li>
    Friday, January 1, 2008 - 6:53pm
  </li>
  <li>
    Monday, November 13, 2008 - 3:12pm
  </li>
  <li>
    Friday, November 1, 2008 - 6:53pm
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: This will work as long as the format remains the same always... good solution :)

Comment: You can extract the dates out of the objects using a `for` loop, then return them foreach as a string instead of an object.

Comment: @Si8, true about the fromat remaining the same, I made that assumption based on both of the dates the OP gave being in the same format.

Comment: @ParkingMaster Thanks for cleaning my answer up =) I rarely remember to worry about readability when answering haha. Whoops!

Comment: No problem, I like improving questions/answers, and making stackoverflow a better place :)

Comment: Sorry I should have been more clear... I just need the day numbers

Answer (score 1):

Uses [momentjs](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/) is one solution:

```js
const test1 = 'Thursday, November 13, 2008 - 3:12pm' // 11/13/2008 is not Monday
const test2 = 'Saturday, November 1, 2008 - 6:53pm' // 11/01/2008 is not Friday
const moment1 = moment(test1, 'dddd, MMMM D, YYYY - h:mma')
const moment2 = moment(test2, 'dddd, MMMM D, YYYY - h:mma')
console.log(moment1.format('dddd, MMMM D, YYYY - h:mma'), moment1.toDate().getTime())
console.log(moment2.format('dddd, MMMM D, YYYY - h:mma'), moment2.toDate().getTime())

const invalid = 'Monday, November 13, 2008 - 3:12pm'
console.log('Invalid Date String', moment(invalid, 'dddd, MMMM D, YYYY - h:mma'))
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/moment@2.29.1/moment.js"></script>
```

Comment: important note about momentjs, from their github: "Moment.js is a legacy project, now in maintenance mode. In most cases, you should choose a different library."

Comment: The OP wanted regex, not a library

Comment: Do you have the import statement for it?

Answer (score 0):

You can easily get all data as

```js
function getDate(str) {
  const [, day, month, date, year] = str.match(/(\w+), (\w+) (\d+), (\d+)/);
  return { day, month, date, year };
}

console.log(getDate("Monday, November 13, 2008 - 3:12pm"));
console.log(getDate("Friday, November 1, 2008 - 6:53pm"));
```

```css
/* This is not a part of answer. It is just to give the output full height. So IGNORE IT */
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

If you want to get particularly the date `13` or `1` then you can do as

```js
function getDate(str) {
  const [, day, month, date, year] = str.match(/(\w+), (\w+) (\d+), (\d+)/);
  return { day, month, date, year };
}

const date = getDate("Monday, November 13, 2008 - 3:12pm");
console.log(+date.date);
// or
// console.log(parseInt(date.date));
```